What's the lowest altitude that can be reached only at orbital velocity?
The higher altitude you wanna reach the more delta-v you need. E.g. the SpaceShipTwo never went higher than 90 km (56 mi), so it could fly well below even 1/10th of orbital speed. However, at some certain targeted apogee, a spacecraft will need to reach at least 7.7 km/s (4.8 mi/s) around engine cut-off to reach it. And around the engine cut-off altitude the orbital velocity will probably be considerabely lower anyway. I wonder what's the minimum apogee in order for a spacecraft to have to go at orbital speed or faster, even if your trajectory is suborbital in that the perigee is within Earth.

If you fly straight up with a long burn with low thrust you could get to a very high altitude with zero final speed. I don't think this question is really answerable in the general case, you can only answer it based on a specific vehicles performance data

I can't tell if this is about SpaceShipTwo or something else. what do you mean, exactly?

@AustinOverton It's about any spacecraft (or anything that has been propelled into a suborbital trajectory) that reaches orbital velocity at engine cut-off altitude. So the question is, what targeted altitude (i.e. apogee) requires orbital velocity even if your trajectory intersects the Earth, that is, you'd fall back onto Earth eventually.

tl;dr: You have to do TWO things to get into an actual safe orbit that will go around the Earth without hitting it.
The expression "orbital velocity" is the minimum speed you would need to make a complete orbit around the Earth without burning up. At that minimum velocity, the only shape that the orbit can be is very nearly a circle (very slightly elliptical if you're following the Karman line in a polar orbit instead of an equatorial orbit.
To get into this minimum, very temporarily safe orbit, you need to do two things at the same time:

achieve a speed of ~7.7 km/s at about 300 km or ~7.84 km/s at 100 km (if you only want to go around roughly once before reentry and death)
make sure the direction of your motion at that speed is tangential and not radial.

If you pass 300 km above Earth at a speed of 7.7 km/s but you are moving in a direction that deviates up by more than a few degrees from tangential, you will go higher for a while, then you'll turn around and die.
If it deviates lower than tangential, you'll "die harder" (and quicker).
If you have "orbital velocity" at the desired altitude, but you find yourself moving straight up, then you are in a [hyperskinny elliptical orbit with eccentricity ~ 1 who's apogee will go much higher, but alas, whose perigee is near the center of the Earth.
The escape velocity at 300 km is 10.9 km/s. If you are going straight up at 7.7 km/s instead of sideways for an orbit, you'll peak out at about 7100 km apogee (above Earth's surface), then fall straight back.
Terminology:
Once all of those "sub-orbital" tourist (and sounding rocket) flights are truly in Earth orbit once they're outside most of the atmosphere and traveling ballistically. It's just that those orbits intersect the earth. So we call them "suborbital".
Basically "orbit" can be any ballistic trajectory outside of substantial atmospheric drag, or it can mean "revolve completely and safely around the Earth at least once".

My question is about what you describe in your latter paragraphs: not reaching an orbit around the Earth, but staying at a trajectory that intersects the Earth, yet having to go at orbital velocity in order to reach a certain apogee. So you say, if I wanted to reach 7100 km (4400 mi) at eccentricity 1, I'll be at 7.7 km/s at the engine cut-off altitude?

@StarCaptain if I understand it correctly, you are asking what your apogee would be if you flew straight upwards at an orbital velocity?

@StarCaptain Why don't you consider revising the title of your question and the text in the main body as well. I think that you are asking something like "If a spacecraft shuts its engines of when it attains orbital velocity at say 400 km, but it's going straight up instead of sideways for orbit, how high would it go? What would its apogee be?" I'm pretty sure the answer is easy: 2 x (6378 + 400) km, but I'm not sure if that's your question yet.

@uhoh No, but you answered my question anyway. The "altitude" in my question is only the apogee I mean. My question is "if you shut down the engines when going straight up, what's the minimum targeted apogee for you to be orbital velocity during the cut-off?". You answered it: 7100 km.

@TheRocketfan In a way, yes. If you have enough thrust to accelerate to orbital velocity when going straight up, and you shut down the engines right when reaching it, how high would you then get (on momentum only)? Obviously, 7100 km (4400 mi) is the answer.

@StarCaptain Oh, great! OK it's good to hear.

"orbital velocity". This could be a bit of a gray area. Von Karman’s calculations were based on instantaneous orbital velocity not whether the vehicle would make it all the way around the Earth. And it was also affected by the aerodynamic lift performance of the vehicle, which is why there were changes in the calculation during his lifetime to account for improved aircraft design. Yet still below 100 km, which was later somewhat arbitrarily selected by the aircraft sports records people. Similarly the velocity needed to make a single orbit is affected by the density and shape of the vehicle

@StevePemberton I'm almost positive that a reasonably aerodynamic spacecraft (say a capsule running on fuel cells/batteries as opposed to a high power synthetic aperture radar satellite with its oversized solar panels) starting in a circular trajectory at 100 km will make it around the Earth a few times if the Sun is in a good mood. I think this was a question and answer here and it was shown via some simple drag estimates and that's where I'm getting it from. I'll go look for it today and if I find it I'll add the link. If I don't, I'll reproduce the calculation.

uhoh - in Jonathan McDowell's 2018 paper on the Karman line he says "Empty rocket stages are frequently left in low orbits of under 200 km and reenter after several days; the final tracked orbit is often between 130 and 140 km". Presumably many of those were in circular orbits. But stages are different than satellites, it would be interesting to find out what the lowest recorded single orbit of a satellite was.
